Debugging Issues with onEdit Trigger in Apps Script: Code Execution Not Working as Expected
I'm encountering an unexpected issue with Apps Script. I'm developing a script that should lock a column when the value of a dropdown menu in Google Sheets changes. After researching online, I found out that the main function should be named onEdit(e) to capture any changes in the sheet. My problem is that part of the code within onEdit is not executing, and I can't figure out why.
Here’s the code I’m using:

function onEdit(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('entre!');

  if (!e) {
    Logger.log("Function not triggered by edit");
    return;
  }

  Logger.log("Edit detected");

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.range;
 
  if (sheet.getName() === "ATTN" && range.getA1Notation() === "M2") {
    Logger.log("Dropdown menu changed");
    var selectedOption = range.getValue();
   
    if (selectedOption === "Yes") {
      handleYesOption();
    } else if (selectedOption === "No") {
      handleNoOption();
    }
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('sali!');
}


The only part that seems to execute are the toast notifications, but the rest of the code doesn’t show messages in the execution log or make changes to the sheet. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?
At first, I tried various approaches and added the code gradually. Initially, I only included the first toast. I then added the second toast in an attempt to force the execution of the code and see if that would resolve the issue.

Parameter "e" on onEdit(e)
Your code will always make this true if (!e) as e in that context is an object there are several same posts here on Stackoverflow you can read about this. You can read about object e here on this article.
What you can do is remove this specific part of the code.
if (!e) {
    Logger.log("Function not triggered by edit");
    return;
  }

More context about your expected result:
It seems that what you want to do is check how it was called, it will always be through the user's input type of edits on Google Sheet.
Due to limited information for your Goal here. I just want to share things that can maybe help you change your target goal based on this parameter to better suit your needs and can be handled by Apps Script(Javascript).
As an object, what you can do is use the null, as per shared to previous posts about objects being boolean. You can also play around e.values to get values from the edit where you can check if it is true or false.
Sample Screenshot:

I have run a scenario where an onEdit is called by another method which can happen but since there is no edit happened on the sheet itself. I will be undefined. Again you can use with your logic.
Reference:
Object E - Triggers
Booleans - MDN

I don't know what your function do but this works for me
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Entry!');
  var sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 13 && e.range.rowStart == 2) {
    e.source.toast("Gate");
    if (e.value === "Yes") {
      handleOption(e.value);
    } else if (e.value === "No") {
      handleOption(e.value);
    }
  }
}

function handleOption(b) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(b);
}

